# Exceljs package not retrieving some cell values

Tags: node.js, csv, xlsx, exceljs

I am using [ExcelJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) package when I retrieve some cells value, it doesn't return the values inside instead it returns some sort of format that I think is a date format sort of.

```js
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook ();
workbook.csv.readFile(path)
.then(worksheet => {
    const seenCell =  worksheet.getCell('A3').value;
    console.log(seenCell);
}
```

When I run this code try to get cell A4 it returns the content which is a string, but trying to get cell A3 returns

`2027-02-11T23:00:00.000Z`

I will like to know which format this is, it looks like a date to me and my data is not date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since CSV files don't contain any information about data types, ExcelJS tries to guess: anything that even remotely looks like a date is converted to a Date. But the test isn't perfect, and something like `123-456-7890` gets converted to `7891-01-13T22:00:00.000Z`.

You can disable date detection by passing empty dateFormats list,
e.g. `workbook.csv.readFile('foo.csv', {dateFormats:[]})`.

Comment: Thank you @pasi,  you are right passing in that argument to the filepath loading method stops it from reading data as Date format. Thank you very much. It solved my problem.